# Jackson deserialize objects with root key

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize JSON using Java:

```
{  
   "Smith":{  
      "id":1,
      "age": 20
   },
   "Carter":{  
      "id":2,
      "age": 21
   }
}
```

to a list of objects of this class:

```
class Person {
    private Long id;
    private Integer age;
    private String name; //here I want to have eg. Smith

    //getters and setters
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: You should create a iterator to iterate over all the keys in your json. Then move the "Smith" to a new key inside called name. I have done something similar once. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535188/custom-deserializer-for-realmobject. 

It might help you

Comment: Are you able to change the structure of the JSON? Cause that would be the easiest option

Comment: Have a look at this answer with custom Desirializer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766712/369946

Comment: Thank you @Matt this is exactly what I was looking for. After some adjustments it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
String json ="your json here " 
Person person = map.readValue(json, Person.class);
```

This is the standard method, 
in your case your json seems bit different , so you have to create a pojo class which is matching to your JSON

Answer (score 0):

This would be through mapping, (in this specific case) for instance:

```
Person myPerson = new ObjectMapper().readValue(YOURJSONHERE, Person.class);
```

The mapper will map the properties specified in your Person model, to the corresponding fields in the JSON. If you have any problems try looking [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

However, the way your JSON is structured suggests it would map to a class 'Smith' or 'Carter', the correct format for using the mapper would therefore be:

```
{
 "Person":{
     "name":"Smith",
     "id": 1,
     "age": 20
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The problem is with the name field. Some more custom mapping is required.

Comment: That is correct, I overlooked it, check the edit. Your JSON and the class dont match, so that would indeed require custom mapping.

Comment: But this is the JSON I'm getting. It's not up to me how it looks like.

Comment: In that case, try looking here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958263/jackson-mapping-some-fields-of-json-to-inner-fields-of-class)

Answer (score 0):

Using [gson](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) is quite simple:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
List<Person> person = gson.fromJson(yourJson, type);
```

Comment: And what about the name field. Will it be properly mapped?

Comment: Ok, I didn't realized that. Probably there is a way but not in my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough working example not following best practices but if you use Jackson elsewhere you should be able to figure it out. You can also register a custom module that can use this same logic for you if its serialized this way in other places as well.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    static class Person {
        private Long id;
        private Integer age;
        private String name; //here I want to have eg. Smith

        public Person() {

        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [id=" + id + ", age=" + age + ", name=" + name + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        String json = "{  \n" +
                "   \"Smith\":{  \n" +
                "      \"id\":1,\n" +
                "      \"age\": 20\n" +
                "   },\n" +
                "   \"Carter\":{  \n" +
                "      \"id\":2,\n" +
                "      \"age\": 21\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode nodes = mapper.readTree(json);

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        nodes.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
            String name = entry.getKey();
            Person person = mapper.convertValue(entry.getValue(), Person.class);
            person.setName(name);
            people.add(person);
        });

        for (Person person : people) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Person [id=1, age=20, name=Smith]
Person [id=2, age=21, name=Carter]
```